# PSQL Add value from row to another value in the same row using triggers

Tags: triggers, psql

I have a test table with three columns (file, qty, qty_total). I will input multiple rows like this for example,    `insert into test_table (file,qty) VALUS (A,5);`. What i want is for on commit is for a trigger to take the value from qty and add it to qty_total. As what will happen is that this value will get updated as this example demonstrates. `Update test_table set qty = 10 where file = A;` So the qty_total is now 15. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this myself. I created a trigger function `CREATE FUNCTION public.qty_total()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$

```
BEGIN
IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
NEW."total" := (OLD.total + NEW.col2);
RETURN NEW;
ELSE
NEW."total" := NEW.col2;
RETURN NEW;
END IF;
```

END;

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.qty_total()
    OWNER TO postgres; This was called by a trigger `CREATE TRIGGER qty_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON public.test
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE qty_total();` now when i insert a new code and value, the value is copied to the total, when it is updated, the value is added to the total and i have my new qty_total. This may not have the best error catching in it, but since i am passing the data from php, i am happy to make sure the errors are caught and removed.